# How to set a pixel in C++?

Tags: c++, graphics

I am attempting to create my own operating system and I am just wondering if there is a way to tell the BIOS to set a VGA pixel on my screen in C++.

Comment: You cannot access screen memory directly under Linux as you could do Under MSDOS 20 years ago.

Comment: Set a pixel... Where? Without using "any of that", the question doesn't even make sense .

Comment: Can I do that in inline assembly?

Comment: Read up on the linux frame buffer. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/fb/framebuffer.txt. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_framebuffer

Comment: Try this library http://www.directfb.org. Its open source so if you are really curious you could look at the source and figure out how they do it ;)

Comment: I don't want to see somebody else's code. I want to make my own.

Comment: It is possible to boot linux with the framebuffer device(fb0) and to set a single pixel to screen. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22919019/unable-to-allocate-memory-with-mmap-in-x86-linux-assembly-language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn on a given pixel, but this requires platform specific code and may not portable when the OS or platform changes.

My understanding is you want direct access to the screen buffer with nothing between stopping you.  Here's the way to go.

**Common Research**
On your platform, find out the graphics controller, brand name and model name, if you are using one.  Search the web for the data sheets on the graphics controller chip.  Most likely, the screen memory is inside the chip and not directly accessible by the CPU.

Next, find out how to access the board that the Graphics Controller resides on.  You may be able to access the Graphics Controller chip directly by I/O ports or memory addresses; or you may have to use an interrupt system.  Research the hardware.

**Linux**
Download a source distribution for the Linux kernel.  Find the graphic driver.  Search the code in the graphic driver to see how the Graphics Controller is manipulated.

For Linux, you will have to write your own graphics driver and rebuild the kernel.  Next you will need to write a program that accesses your driver and turns on the pixel.  Research "Linux driver API".  There are books available on writing Linux drivers and the standard API that they use.

**Windows**
Windows uses the same concept of drivers.  You will have to write your own Windows driver and let the OS know you want to use it.  Your driver will talk to the Graphics Controller.  There are books available about writing Windows drivers.  After writing the driver, you will need to write a demo program that uses your driver.

**Embedded Systems**
Embedded systems range from simple to complex as far as displays go.  This simplest embedded system uses memory that the display views.  Any writes to this memory are immediately reflected on the display.

The more complex embedded systems use Graphic Controllers to control the display.  You would need to get the data sheets on the Graphic Controller, figure out how to set it up, then how to turn on a pixel.

**Driver Writers**
Drivers are not an easy thing to write.  Most drivers are written by teams of experts and take months to produce.  Graphic Controller chips are becoming more and more complex as new features are added.  The driver must be able to support new features and the older models.  Not an easie issue.

**Summary**
If you really want to access a pixel directly, go ahead.  It may require more research and effort that using an Off The Shelf (OTS) library.  Most people in the industry use OTS libraries or frameworks (such as QT, wxWidgets and XWindows).  Drivers are only rewritten or modified for performance reasons or to support new graphics hardware.  Driver writing is not a simple task and requires a quality development process as well as a verification strategy.

Good luck on writing your pixel.  I hope your library has something better to offer than the many graphic libraries already in existence.

Answer (score 3):

C as a language does not provide any built-in graphics capabilities. If you want graphics, you have to use some OS-specific library.

Aside from that, modern operating systems generally don't allow any old program to poke around in memory however it wants to. Instead, they use intermediates called drivers and, yes, graphics libraries and APIs such as OpenGL.

If you really want to do it yourself get a copy of MS-DOS and dig up some old VGA specs and start from there.

Comment: I wanted to just set a pixel

Comment: Can I set a pixel using inline assembly?

Comment: @user3140258: No, the graphics card controls the screen, and the OS controls the graphics card.  Your only option is to talk to the OS/graphics card, via library calls.  Such as... OpenGL.  That _is_ the lowest layer we have access to.

Comment: I'm trying to CREATE a library. And one that will talk directly to the graphics card.

Comment: Besides, what made you think that I was using C? The tag and name says C++.

Comment: C, C++, Pascal, Basic, asm... the same principles apply.

Comment: I believe this should be doable with a bash script. (sorry - couldn't resist)